# how to populate an array using anither?

Tags: arrays, vb6

I'm working on an excersice of filling one array using another one . To things uneasy , I 'm trying to fill starting from a certain point in the first array.I'm using Vb6

Comment: This is not a code writing service nor a tutorial service.  Many here will help you with the code you have, if you include it.  See: [Ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following example project:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Form_Click()
  Dim intIndex As Integer
  Dim intSrc(10) As Integer
  Dim intResult() As Integer
  'fill source array with some etxt values
  For intIndex = 0 To UBound(intSrc)
    intSrc(intIndex) = intIndex * intIndex
  Next intIndex
  'fill resulting array with subset 3 to 7
  intResult = FromArray(intSrc, 3, 7)
  'show resulting array
  For intIndex = 0 To UBound(intResult)
    Print CStr(intIndex) & " : " & CStr(intResult(intIndex))
  Next intIndex
End Sub

Private Function FromArray(intSrc() As Integer, intFrom As Integer, intTo As Integer) As Integer()
  Dim intIndex As Integer
  Dim intResult() As Integer
  'resize resulting array to appropriate size
  ReDim intResult(intTo - intFrom) As Integer
  'fill resulting array with values from source array
  For intIndex = 0 To UBound(intResult)
    intResult(intIndex) = intSrc(intFrom + intIndex)
  Next intIndex
  'return resulting array
  FromArray = intResult
End Function
```

When you run it and click on the form you will see the resulting array.

The project contains some basic array handling functions. try some different values to see how it works.

Also try some weird values like `intResult = FromArray(intSrc, 7, 3)`, and try to understand the error.